# How do bind/map a device to Rancher?

Tags: docker, kubernetes, rancher, octoprint

When I run the command on my SBC:

```sh
docker run --volume $(pwd):/home/octoprint --device /dev/ttyUSB0:/dev/ttyACM0 -p 5000:5000 --name octoprint octoprint/octoprint:1.4.0-python3
```

Everything works normally; I can open the octoprint screen and my 3D printer is recognized without any problems.

However, when I try to run the equivalent `--device /dev/ttyUSB0:/dev/ttyACM0` to be mapped as any type of volume as possible, I am unable to make an equivalent configuration.

Please, how do I get Rancher to recognize a `--device`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you are talking about Kubernetes Rancher. The [common](https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/issues/5607#issuecomment-258195005) way is to use `privileged` in the [SecurityContext](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/configure-pod-container/security-context/) of your Pod or Container.

For example:

```yaml
  containers:
  - name: sbc
    securityContext:
      privileged: true
    volumeMounts:
    - mountPath: /dev/ttyUSB0
      name: ttyacm
  volumes:
  - name: ttyacm
    hostPath:
      path: /dev/ttyACM0
```

A more advanced way of supporting host devices is [Device Plugins](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/extend-kubernetes/compute-storage-net/device-plugins/). But I believe of standard USB the above should work. You might also want to use [NodeAffinity](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/scheduling-eviction/assign-pod-node/) to make sure that your Pod lands where your device is.

✌️